# MeteorJS publication extending beyond scope

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-publications

I have the following templates:

```
<template name="reportsContent">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tabs-content" data-content="summary">
            <div class="tabs-content-wrapper">
                {{> reportsSummary }}
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-content" data-content="patients">
            <div class="tabs-content-wrapper">
                {{> reportsPatients }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="reportsSumary">
    ....
</template>

<template name="reportsPatients">
    ....
</template>
```

I've attached a publication to the `reportsSummary` template, yet it seems to be extending to the `reportsPatients` template too. I'm not sure why since I've followed the correct method to define pubs/subs (I think...).

I know that it's extending to `reportsPatients` because I if I return `Appointments.find()` from a `reportsPatients` helper without subscribing to a publication, I'm getting the data that's also in `reportsSummary`

Here's my publication:

```
Meteor.publish('appointments.day.patients', function () {

    var thisMonth = new RegExp(moment().format('MMM YYYY'));

    return Appointments.find({
        date_created: { $regex: thisMonth }
    }, { fields: { date_created: 1 } });
});
```

And here's my subscription:

```
Template.reportsSummary.onCreated(function () {
    this.subscribe('appointments.day.patients');
});
```

It's not that what I have is breaking any functionalities per se. I'm just worried about efficiency when the app has a whole lot of data that it has to sift through. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Publications have no scope. If the data is published to the client, it will be available everywhere until that subscription is undone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything, that is the normal behaviour in Meteor. Data published from server has no scope. Once data is published to client, all client could access them, even code run in browser console could do that.

These published data will only be cleared in client when the subscription used to subscribe for them is closed. Like in your example, because you use `this.subscribe` inside `reportsSummary` template so this subscription will be closed when `reportsSummary` is destroyed (when the `onDestroyed` event is fired).

It is a best practice in Meteor to always put a query in `collection.find` to get documents. This way your operation is explicit about what you expect to get, and prevent unwanted documents to be returned.